# ASUS KPGE-D16 With ADM 6344 Running Ubuntu 12.04 Very Slow Processing

Tags: drivers, asus

I set this machine up as a workstation specifically for CFD work.  I have 64G memory, 24 cores processing, and fastest Disks available.  Running the same CFD model on my Windows quad core notebook (slower processor and Linux applications ported to windows) is 50% faster than anything I can do on the ASUS.  I used cpufrequtil to try to directly control cpu speed, but virtually no change.  Are there some secret settings or utilities that will speed up this sudo-beast?  I suspect the cpus are loafing along at some slow speed as the fans don't even speed up in the middle of calculations.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: BIOS up to date? Why not Ubuntu 14.04? Did you try some other Benchmarks?